# Open a file with C++ and output the text that is in the file

Tags: c++

I am trying to open a file with C++ and output the text that is in the file. I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is what I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char fileName[50];
    ifstream infile;


    cout << "Enter the name of the file you would like to open: ";
    cin.getline(fileName, 50);
    infile.open(fileName);


    if(!infile.is_open())
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char line[75];
     infile >> line;
    while (infile.good()) 
    {
        cout << line << " ";
        infile >> line;
    }


    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

After I input the file name and press enter the CMD prompt just closes. I know that the file exist, but I cannot figure out why it is exiting. Obviously it is because of the exit command, but it should be open. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try entering the absolute pathname. Your development environment is probably executing code from a different directory than you think it does. Also, use `std::string` instead of character arrays. This is C++, not C.

Comment: It appears that you are using Visual Studio (given you are doing a `system("pause")`. I recommend using the debugger to step through your code to see where the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to read/write the file line by line; C++ already supports to copy the file in one step. You also should use `string` instead of `char[]` for your strings; on one hand it means that you don't need to restrict the maximal length of your strings to some arbitrary length (what if your file's pathname has more than 50 characters, or the file has lines with more than 75 characters?

Note also that your file copying code is erroneous: It will remove all whitespace from the file, as `infile >> line` does *not* read a line (use readline for that), but a word, *discarding whitespace.*

Also, your code should give an error message if it couldn't open the file, instead of just silently returning (you *do* provide an error return, which is very good, but unless you call it from something that actually gives you feedback on the error return, you'll never learn about it.

Finally, the `system("pause")` should probably be done in an RAII class, so it is guaranteed to be exited on return (however, `exit` will not call destructors, so unless you want to use `atexit`, you should use `return` in `main`` instead). A better idea would, however, be to not put this into the code, but instead run it in a terminal that doesn't immediately close after the program finishes.

Here's a program that implements those suggestions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
  // make sure that system("pause") is called on all exit paths
  struct cleanup
  {
    ~cleanup() { std::system("pause"); }
  } do_cleanup;

  // get the file name
  std::string filename;
  std::cout << "Enter the name of the file you would like to open: ";
  std::getline(std::cin,filename);
  if (!std::cin)
  {
    std::cerr << "Failed to read the file name.\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  // open the file
  std::ifstream infile(filename.c_str());
  if (!infile)
  {
    std::cerr << "Could not open file: " << filename << "\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  // print the file
  std::cout << infile.rdbuf();

  // close the file
  infile.close();
  if (!infile)
  {
    std::cerr << "Could not properly close file: " << filename << "\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a `char[]`. You've even `#include`d `string` so just use that.

```
string fileName;
cout << "Enter the name of the file you would like to open: ";
cin >> fileName;
// or
// getline(cin, fileName);

ifstream infile(fileName);

if (infile.fail()) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

string line;

while (infile >> line) {
    cout << line << " ";
}

system("pause");
return 0;
```

I also modified a few things to make it a bit cleaner.

Comment: I still get the exact same result. The window shuts immediately.

Comment: I suspect that your file is in the wrong folder. Is it in the same folder as the project file?

Comment: Your code will fail if the file name has any spaces in it. Using getline for reading it is one thing done right in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. Yes the file was in the wrong folder. It was a newb oversight!